# Laravel Input array of objects to api routes

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, laravel-request

I'm passing the following request to laravel api, but when I dump the input request, Laravel is returning an empty array.

```
{
  "expense_type" : "payment",
  "description" : "test",
  "notes" : "My notes",
  "expense_date": "2019-01-15",
  "cost" : 100.50,
  "group_id" : 1,
  "shares" : [
    {
        "user_id" : 1,
        "paid_share" : 100.50,
        "owed_share" : 00.00
    },
    {
        "user_id" : 2,
        "paid_share" : 00.00,
        "owed_share" : 50.25
    },
    {
        "user_id" : 3,
        "paid_share" : 00.00,
        "owed_share" : 50.25
    }
  ]
 }
```

The output when dumping the input `$request->all()` is `[]`

can some one help if there is something wrong in the request

Comment: try `$request->headers->set('content-type','application/json');` in the body of function before you access data

Comment: @MehravishTemkar

I did but no luck, also I'm sending the same header from the postman

Answer (score 0):

When you send data in request as json data then `$request->all()` will always return empty. In order to access data in `$request->all()` variable you have to send form data not json data.

So, when json data is sent through api, you can access it as array in the controller like this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

Now, you can access the values like `$data['expense_type']`

I hope you understand.

Comment: @ReiahPaulSam with above code i've written, you can access all the data in $data variable what's the problem ?

Comment: In Laravel 
`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);` is returning null

Comment: @ReiahPaulSam You have to write the above code in the laravel controller function

Comment: Also, When I removed the `shares` array from the input the whole input is being retrieved in the controller and Request Validation file where we write rules.

Comment: @ReiahPaulSam Then it's difficult to understand